# Need help accessing a virtual server using Flask

Tags: python, flask, webapi

So for our last coding projects we've set up a web API that runs on local host. But now he has set up a virtual server for us to use along with usernames and passwords to use as well as which ports we are alllowed to use. I have my current code here. On the last line it used to be localhost and the port was 8080 but I changed it to reflect the new server we were given. However, it doesn't work and I couldn't seem to find a solution online. I also have the IP address and it didn't work either. I wasn't sure how to add my username and password to the mix as well as I am sure it is needed to access the server.

```
from flask_cors import CORS
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, Blueprint
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint
from routes import request_api
import ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_cert_chain('certificate.pem', 'key.pem')
APP = Flask(__name__)

SWAGGER_URL = '/swagger'
API_URL = '/static/swagger.json'
SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    SWAGGER_URL,
    API_URL,
    config={
        'app_name': "Kales Flask Project"
    }
)
APP.register_blueprint(SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)


APP.register_blueprint(request_api.get_blueprint())


@APP.errorhandler(400)
def handle_400_error(_error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Misunderstood'}), 400)


@APP.errorhandler(404)
def handle_404_error(_error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)

@APP.errorhandler(401)
def handle_401_error(_error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Invalid Key Provided'}), 401)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    CORS = CORS(APP)
    APP.run(host='easel4.cs.utsarr.net', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 12145)), ssl_context=context)
```

Here is the output when I attempt to run this code

```
C:\Users\kingk\PycharmProjects\AdvanceSoft>python webapi.py
 * Serving Flask app "webapi" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webapi.py", line 44, in <module>
    APP.run(host='10.100.201.3', port=12145, ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\kingk\PycharmProjects\AdvanceSoft\yes\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\kingk\PycharmProjects\AdvanceSoft\yes\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1009, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "C:\Users\kingk\PycharmProjects\AdvanceSoft\yes\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 962, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "C:\Users\kingk\PycharmProjects\AdvanceSoft\yes\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 805, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "C:\Users\kingk\PycharmProjects\AdvanceSoft\yes\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 698, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "C:\Users\kingk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\kingk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\kingk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. With the info you provide we can't help you much. What do you mean by " it doesn't work at all"? Do you get an error? Which one? Post the stack trace. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `host='easel4.cs.utsarr.net'` is the problem. The Flask documentation of the `run` method of the [Application object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#application-object) recommends:

> host – the hostname to listen on. Set this to '0.0.0.0' to have the server available externally as well. Defaults to '127.0.0.1' or the host in the SERVER_NAME config variable if present.